# How many sequences of length n satisfy these constraints?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

I want to count the number of unique sequences of length n with the following constraints.

1. Each element of the sequence is an integer in $\lbrace 1,2,\dots,n\rbrace$.
2. Each two adjacent elements of the sequence differ at most by 1.
3. At least one element on the sequence is equal to 1.

The problem is to find a formula f(n) that returns the number of distinct sequences satisfying these 3 constraint.

Comment: Does "vector of length $n$" mean square root of the sum of the squares of the components is $n$? or does it mean the number of components is $n$?

Comment: What is "absolute value difference"?

Comment: If you write "integer sequences", then the first condition is unnecessary.

Comment: it means number of components is n. or the cardinality is n.
The absolute value difference is the abs(a-b).

Comment: The condition 1 is to restrain the maximum value and minimum value.

Comment: Just check yourself that conditions 2 & 3 imply condition 1 under the assumption that you have a sequence of positive integers (okay, I should have said positive above)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming "vector of length $n$" means the number of components is $n$.  In this case, the answer is $3^{n-1}$.  I will create a bijection between vectors ($n$-tuples) of the form described and words of length $n-1$ on an alphabet of three symbols.

Suppose given a vector $v = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ satisfying the three conditions, and consider the sequence 
$$D(v) = (a_2 - a_1, a_3 - a_2, \ldots, a_n - a_{n-1}).$$
  By condition (2), D(v) has all entries equal to 0 or $\pm 1$. Conversely, given a sequence d, the condition
$$D(v) = d$$
determines $v$ up to addition of a vector of the form $(a, a, \ldots, a)$. But conditions (1) and (3) exactly state that the minimum component of $v$ must equal $1$; so $D(v)$ uniquely determines $v$.

Thus, 
$$v \mapsto D(v)$$
is a bijection from the set of vectors we wish to count to the set of $(n-1)$-tuples with each entry $0$ or $\pm 1$.